# Why does SQLite LEAD always return NULL?

Tags: sqlite, window-functions

I'm running:

```
sqlite> .version
SQLite 3.27.1 2019-02-08 13:17:39 0eca3dd3d38b31c92b49ca2d311128b74584714d9e7de895b1a6286ef959a1dd
zlib version 1.2.11
clang-10.0.0
```

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO ( 
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  SORT REAL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT 0, 
  NAME TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TRIGGER FOO_sort_after_insert_trigger
  AFTER INSERT ON FOO FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      UPDATE FOO
      SET SORT = (
        SELECT IFNULL(MAX(SORT), 0) + 1
        FROM FOO
      )
      WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
    END;
```

Populated thusly:

```
sqlite> select * from foo order by sort;
ID|SORT|NAME
1|1.0|A
2|3.5|B
4|4.0|D
3|5.0|C
```

I'm trying to find the next `sort` value after row `2`'s `sort`, but I always get the default value, but I expect to get `4.0`:

```
sqlite> select lead(sort, 1, -42) over (order by sort) as next_sort 
        from foo 
        where id = 2;
next_sort
-42
```

Answer (score 1):

Caution: [SQLite window functions are only available in version 3.25.0 and later](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#history), and if you're using SQLite with Android, even `Android API 28` only has `SQLite 3.22.0`, and [older Android versions have even older SQLites](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).

[SQLite window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) operate over the result set, not the table. Thus, my problem was my `where id = 2` clause. This limited the result set to 1 row, and thus `LEAD` always returned the default value. To accomplish my goal, I had to include enough results in the result set for the window function to have access to the next row:

```
sqlite> select next_sort 
        from ( select id, 
                      lead(sort, 1, -42) 
                        over (order by sort) as next_sort 
               from foo
        ) where id = 2;
next_sort
4.0
```

Comment: "window functions operate over the result set" ... this isn't completely accurate.  The problem you were facing is that `WHERE` happens _before_ the analytic functions get evaluated.  So the `id = 2` records would be thrown out before `LEAD` evaluates.  Materializing the analytic function first in a subquery before applying `WHERE` is a standard way to deal with this problem.

Comment: `Materializing the analytic function first in a subquery before applying WHERE is a standard way to deal with this problem` isn't that what I did?

Comment: I appreciate that. I'm trying to understand the difference. What does `So the id = 2 records would be thrown out before LEAD evaluates` mean? Wouldn't the `WHERE` case all `id != 2` records to be thrown out?

Comment: Yes, but in your answer the discarding of records is happening _after_ the lead has already been calculated.  So, that could make a difference.

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused about how my wording is wrong. You said `the problem you were facing is that WHERE happens before the analytic functions get evaluated. So the id = 2 records would be thrown out before LEAD evaluates.`, and I don't understand how that's different from `SQLite window functions operate over the result set, not the table`.

Comment: What you said is not strictly true, because the result of analytic functions themselves _are part of the result set_.  To operate on the entire result set, you actually have to use a subquery, which is what you correctly did.

Comment: Thanks! So what is the correct way to phrase it the portion of the results that the `WHERE` clause trims out?